# Kubernetes: how do I turn on the TTLAfterFinished feature gate on my cluster (v1.15.3)

Tags: kubernetes

I've been unable to figure out how to use the following directive to turn on a feature: `--feature-gate="TTLAfterFinished=true"`

Has anybody found some good turning this feature on? I'm using a bare metal v1.15.3 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature **TTLAfterFinished** needs to be enabled for both API server and controller manager.

To verify whether it's enabled, check the beginning of both apiserver log and controller-manager log and look for **TTLAfterFinished** to see if the feature gate is enabled.

Please see the instructions below for enabling the feature in both the API server and controller manager, and for specifying the options in your API objects to make use of the feature.

Here are instructions: [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes-io-vnext-staging.netlify.com/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/), [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/).

Comment: So how would one find out it should be enabled for the API server and controller manager, but not for scheduler? It does not mention anything about that in the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/ I don't think it would be a problem to also enable it for the schedular (it will just do nothing I guess?)